# How to change the default command character in linux screen from cntr+a to cntr+t

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have been using screen in Linux and in some systems I get the default command character in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but in others I get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. How can I change the configuration in those with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

In the `~/.screenrc` file, you should have:

```
escape ^Bt
```

This will remap screen's Escape key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I did a find with find ~/ -name .screenrc and it return nothing, so I don't have a file .screenrc in my home folder. Any other clue?

Comment: create the `~/.screenrc` file and it will be loaded the next time you start `screen`

Comment: Why B?  Would 'escape ^Xt' also work?

Comment: this didn't work for me for trying to map to ctrl+J. I had to put in screenrc `escape ^Jj` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `escape` command to change command character.

In yoru case, try to `Ctrl + A` `:escape ^Ta` on your running screen(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

If you wish to use escape character(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) everytime, you write to `~/.screenrc`

> escape ^Ta